# nest server won't start via start:dev on NestJS application

Tags: node.js, nest

it shows "Starting incremental compilation" after that it is not starting server
,nest start works however problem is happening only in watch mode

tried restarting my machine, tried creating new project same issue

Answer (score 0):

I used this https://github.com/nestjs/typescript-starter.git project

instead of nest cli